# HTML5+javascript , How to connect with database like oracle,msql

Tags: javascript, database, html, web-services, rest

Here is my question:

I want to build webapplication using javascript and HTML5. CAn anyone tell me how can I make a connection to database like oracle or mysql? Because in my application I need to load the data from databse into HTML5 page.

Can I use webservice ?
Can I use rest ?

What are the options and possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly connect to any of the databases from javascript or html.
For that you have to make a server which listen to the requests from your javascript and talk to your db and return results to your javascript. 
Possible options include
1) Rails in the backend based on Ruby
2) J2ee server based on Java
3) php or python
4) Node server based on node.js
There are many other possibilities also but these are the most used ones.

Answer (score 0):

you may use ajax to call php and do transactions like it is illustrated here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp